# Why nested function work in turboc++ but not in gnu g++?

Tags: c, function, static, declaration

I have tried to create program with nested function in main() like

```
 main(){
     func1(){}
     func2(){}

     func1();
     func2();
 }
```

but at compile time it gives error like

error: static declaration of 'disp_mat' follows non-static declaration

i am using gnu g++;

however i have not faced this kind of problem in turboc++.

So is there anything i am doing wrong or it is not allowed in g++;

Comment: Show us the actual code

Comment: I do not see `get_mat` function there

Comment: where does you main function end?

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't have that error, because it doesn't have the `static` keyword anywhere. Any code that you want us to look at needs to be in the question itself. See [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: If you're using the GCC extension 'nested functions', state so clearly.  It is non-standard C.  It could lead to the error you're reporting, and the text of your question suggests you might be doing that.

Comment: Now i am going to be banned from asking more questions, Thankyou for your Downvotes.TATA BYE BYE.

Answer (score 0):

1)declare function on top if you are using it before definition:

```
 void disp_mat(void); //declaration
```

2)call function from main :

```
   disp_mat(); //Usage
```

3)define function :

```
//defifnition
void disp_mat(){
    for(r=0;r<size;r++){
        for(c=0;c<size;c++)
            printf("%.2f\t", mat[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

4) your code should look like this :

```
void disp_mat(void); /*declaration*/
main()
{
     //some other code code
     disp_mat(); /*Usage*/
}
/*defifnition*/
void disp_mat(){
    for(r=0;r<size;r++){
        for(c=0;c<size;c++)
            printf("%.2f\t", mat[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```